# Django 'User' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django

I don't know why I'm getting this error..

> [ 'User' object is not iterable ]

here I want to print (logged in user) followers on the home page. apart from error is my models.py is right ? for followers and following mechanism.

model

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    following = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='following')
    followers = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='followers')
```

view

```
def profile(request):
   current_user = request.user
   twi = Follow.objects.get(pk=current_user.id)
   display = twi.followers
   return render(request,'home.html' , 
       {'detail':display,'user':current_user,})
```

template

```
{% for o in detail %}
<h1>o.followers</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why *are* you trying to iterate over it?

Comment: user is just request.user not a list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a mixup in your logic, your `detail` refers to `followers` but the field itself is a link to a singular user, you either need to make this field a ManyToMany relationship, or use a reverse lookup to find what a user follows.

<sub>(Theres also a stray comma in your context dict which may cause issues later on..</sub>

Answer (score 2):

get returns a single queryset and you cannot iterate over it, if you use get

use this in template

```
   <h1>{{ detail.followers }}</h1>
```

or if you need multiple

in view

```
twi = Follow.objects.filter(pk=current_user.id)
```

and change this line

```
display = twi.followers
```

to

```
display = twi
```

and in template

```
{% for o in detail %}
   <h1>{{ o.followers }}</h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: get doesn't return a queryset though, it returns a single instance of the model's class. `.filter` returns a queryset, `.get` is like doing `.filter()[0]` except it also fails if the length of the filter's result is bigger than 1

Answer (score 0):

if you want to iterate over 'detail' and do not want to change your code in the templates, use a [filter()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) query and set `'display' to result of your filter query.`

or if you are not planning to change your views code you can edit the template code from

`{% for o in detail %}
   <h1>o.followers</h1>
{% endfor %}`

to just

`<h1>{{detail}}</h1>`

Comment: If you add some explanation like others did then it would be great.